# Understanding if statement syntax in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

So I have a question for you all. Below I have a code that I recently acquired from here, and when I leave it alone it works fine, however once I place it in an if statement, it somehow doesn't like to work.

```
if (apollo.Contains("Savings found"))
{
    int apolloSavings = apollo.Count(line => line.Contains("Savings found:"));
    Console.WriteLine("In Apollo, there were " + apolloSavings + " PNRS);
}
```

I am thinking that since the code inside the if statement is acting like a loop, that it counters the if statement, but I am not sure. When you explain what the problem, please also give a description on what I can do to change that syntax to make it work in the if statement.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it somehow doesn't like to work"?

Comment: The code inside the if block will not be executed if the statement inside your `if` isn't true. "I am thinking that since the code inside the if statement is acting like a loop" does not make any sense.

Comment: @JonSkeet what I mean by "somehow doesn't work" is if I delete that if statement, the code will run. However if I do not delete that the code will not run.

Comment: Then presumably the condition isn't met. The whole point of an if statement is only to run the body if the condition is met.

Comment: I guess you are not aware that Contains used in this way is casesensitive?

Comment: Then can you explain how I can make that condition meet? Because I can assure you that the condition is met since the phrase "Savings found" is in there, especially since everything works once the if statement is gone

Comment: How can we know how to make the condition meet? Tell us what apollo actually is and whats exactly is in there and someone might have an idea.

Comment: There is no element "Savings found". There may be an element that contains that string. Try `if(apollo.Any(item => item.Contains("Savings found")))` (edit: posted this as answer, as I intended to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no element "Savings found". There may be an element that contains that string. Try `if(apollo.Any(item => item.Contains("Savings found")))`

Comment: apparrently my rep isn't high enough, but once I get it to the value necessary I will happily :)